# How to save computed values in DataFrame if apply method fails?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a method that writes values into an excel file. However, the dataframe needs to be completed and the apply value must not fail in order for it to write. Since I am working on thousands of rows, I want it to write into the output excel if apply crashes and save whatever progress I had. This will help a lot if I want to stop the script midway or if an error occurs unexpectedly.

Here's some dummy code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')

df["numberSquared"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: squared(x["number"]), axis=1) 

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: how about passing a function that do not fail, and by that I mean function that do something if an error is found that do not stop the operation...

Comment: I've added multiple try/excepts inside the original function so that it would not crash. However, there are certain situations (such as losing power) where the code will be forced to stop. I want a backup solution to be able to save the information I computed so that thousands of values I computed are not lost. Thank you for the suggestion though, I appreciate it.

Comment: the only way I can think of guarding even against losing power is to write in disk as you process somehow, like maybe save some intermediary state in some temporary file(s) so you can resume from there if forced to stop and when done delete the temp files you created as they aren't longer needed

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a try/except inside of your lambda function, here is some code i wrote up:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"number":[1,2,3,'4',5]})

def squared(i):
    try:
        x = i*i
    except:
        x = i
    return x

df["numberSquared"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: squared(x["number"]), axis=1) 

df.head()
```

here is a pic of the code executed in my environment:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have been doing this to make sure that apply does not fail. I just want to know if there is a more efficient way or a way pandas will allow us to write after each row so in the case that apply fails, I don't lose hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use try/except and export you data frame to an excel file in catch part. so if there were some errors in apply  you can be sure that you have your data frame exported to an excel file after the error

```
def squared(x):
    try:
      # some thing that might have errors      
    except:
      # do some thing diffrent to this special case
```

**important note:**

this works but in case where your code **IS NOT** fragile
and as you mentioned "*if an error occurs unexpectedly*" i assume that you do not have try/except in your code to make it an expected error.
so in this case it seems that the only way is to export your data frame to an excel file before applying any change to each row but that is not efficient(also you can export it after applying changes to for example 200 or 300 rows but again it is not very clever)
so my advice is to make you errors happen expectedly and use appoparite try/except so that crashing does not happen to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sometimes I'm running code overnight because I have lots of data to process so when I say an error occurs unexpectedly, its more towards if my computer crashes or if the power shuts down. I have been using try/excepts to make sure that apply does not fail but in case of an emergency, I don't want to be losing hours of work.